# como fazer combobox modificar uma combobox com itens do banco de dados java desktop?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, aplicação-desktop

Eu consegui fazer mas so funciona com itens pré selecionados.

```
    CidadeDAO cidadeDAO = new CidadeDAO(connection);
    EstadoDAO estadoDao = new EstadoDAO(connection);
    List<ModeloEstado> estados = estadoDao.lista();
    jComboBoxEstado.removeAllItems();
    jComboBoxCidade.removeAllItems();

    for(ModeloEstado c : estados ){

       jComboBoxEstado.addItem(c.getNome());
   }

    jComboBoxEstado.setSelectedIndex(4);

    System.err.println(jComboBoxEstado.getSelectedItem());
    List<ModeloCidades> cidadeCombo = cidadeDAO.buscaIdPorEstado((String) jComboBoxEstado.getSelectedItem());
    for(ModeloCidades c : cidadeCombo){
        jComboBoxCidade.addItem(c.getNome());
   }
```

mas eu gostaria de fazer com que ao selecionar um item na combobox estado, modifique a cobobox cidade com os itens já cadastrados no banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve adicionar um evento ao primeiro combobox e quando você selecionar algum valor nele, deverá chamar um outro método que busca no banco os dados relativos ao primeiro (passando ID de busca ou semelhante).

Exemplo:

```
combobox1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        /* Chame aqui o método de busca no banco de dados passando o valor 
           selecionado no combobox1 e povoe o combobox2.
        */
    }
});
```

Comment: Funcionou aqui muito obrigado pela ajuda.